# Android how to trim sharedpreferences name

Tags: android, arrays, sharedpreferences, spinner, android-sharedpreferences

I'm getting all sharedpreferences created by my app and I insert them in a spinner but every sharedpreferences displayed like "example.xml" etc. I want to trim .xml extension let them just names like "example".

```
File prefsdir = new File(getApplicationInfo().dataDir,"shared_prefs");
   if(prefsdir.exists() && prefsdir.isDirectory()){
        String[] list = prefsdir.list();
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,list);
        Spinner sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.tum_ilaclar);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
   }
```

Comment: simply replace `".xml"` with `""`.

Comment: I got it but there is an array not a single variable.

Comment: Join the array to a string, do the replacement, and re-split the string into an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this create a new method:

```
String[] getList(String[] list){
    String values[] = new String[list.length];
    for(int i=0; i<list.length; i++){
        String value = list[i];
        values[i]=value.contains(".xml")?value.replace(".xml",""):value;
    }
    return values;
}
```

Then in your code change :

```
String[] list = prefsdir.list();
```

to

```
String[] list = getList(prefsdir.list());
```

This will remove the .xml part.

Comment: You can avoid checking for `contains()` and save some execution time.

Comment: sorry , I couldn't understand .

Comment: it gave an error String[] list = getList(prefsdir.list()); can't resolve getlist

Comment: I have just optimize the code a bit more. I the old approach I was referencing list[i] multiple times.